# tar command writing to standard output

Tags: tar

I am curious to understand whether there is any difference in the below two syntax of how **tar** command writes its output to STDOUT channel

```
tar -czf - /src_dir

tar -czf -O /src_dir
```

From the **man** page, i read this. However there is nothing for '-'

```
-O, --to-stdout : extract files to standard output
```

Are they interchangeable without any portability issues?

Comment: If you want "portable" use `tar cf - /src_dir" | gzip`. Notice no hyphen introducing the flags, and no built-in compression. I first used that style in the '80s.

Comment: @Kusalananda said it all, `-O` is equivalent to `-f -`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the `-f` removed from the second command, the two should be equivalent (with GNU `tar`).  Writing to `-` using `-f` is not documented in the GNU `tar` manual, but [its `info` manual says](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_chapter/tar_6.html#SEC106):

> If you use '-' as an ARCHIVE-NAME, 'tar' reads the archive from
>       standard input (when listing or extracting files), or **writes it to
>       standard output (when creating an archive)**.  If you use '-' as an
>       ARCHIVE-NAME when modifying an archive, 'tar' reads the original archive
>       from its standard input and writes the entire new archive to its
>       standard output.

With `-f` in the second command, it would write to a file called `-O` and would produce no data on its standard output.